# How to generate a mixed type list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, casting

I have a list of Strings in Python, of which some can be cast into floats (float-candidates), while others cannot. I'd like to cast all of the float-candidates into floats, while keeping the Strings...

Example:

```
test_array=["string","3.45","hello","-7.91035"]
```

This should become

```
floats=[3.45,-7.91035]
strings=["string","hello"]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @quamrana.. I would, but honestly I didn't try anything beforehand! I wasn't sure how to start.

Comment: Well, on stackoverflow, you should at least try something. No try == no votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to convert the given string into a float, but if that does not work - and throws an error - just act as if it is a string. This works for your dummy example but may not work in advanced cases such as custom objects! Be careful when using this kind of method

```py
def typed_lists(l):
    floats = []
    strings = []
    for item in l:
        try:
            floats.append(float(item))
        except ValueError:
            strings.append(item)
    
    return floats, strings


test_array = ["string","3.45","hello","-7.91035"]

fls, strs = typed_lists(test_array)

print(fls)
# [3.45, -7.91035]
print(strs)
# ['string', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [11]: test_array=["string","3.45","hello","-7.91035"]

In [12]: from collections import defaultdict

In [13]: data = defaultdict(list)

In [14]: for i in test_array:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         data["float"].append(float(i))
    ...:     except ValueError:
    ...:         data["string"].append(i)
    ...:

In [15]: dict(data)
Out[15]: {'float': [3.45, -7.91035], 'string': ['string', 'hello']}
```